# Is there a representation of a directed line in 3D where equivalence exclusively implies collinearity?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Is there a representation of a directed line in 3D such that for any 2 lines, they are collinear if and only if the parameters of their representations are the same?

In addition, I would also need to know how to derive such a representation from 2 vertices on the line.

I have done some searching on this site, and I found an answer for a different question explaining that directed lines in 3D have 4 degrees of freedom: 2 for the direction of the line, and 2 for the point intersecting the line on the origin-intersecting plane said direction vector is a normal of. For simplicity I could represent the plane with 6 degrees, 3 for the unit direction vector of the line, and 3 for the intersection point of the line on the aforementioned plane. My problem is in deriving these from 2 vertices in the line.

This is for a computational geometry algorithm that needs to test collinearity of directed line segments in a set against others in the set. Given a representation with this property, I could potentially derive a hash function for it such that 2 lines with similar hashes are likely to be nearly collinear. This would allow my algorithm to be linear in the best case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you don’t know how to compute a unit direction vector $\mathbf n$ from the coordinates $P$ and $Q$ of two points? Once you have that, the equation of the plane is just $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x=0$ and you can find many questions and answers here and elsewhere on the Web about how to compute the intersection of a line and plane. Many of them involve solving equations, but this intersection can be computed directly: A convenient way is to observe that since the plane goes through the origin, it is the orthogonal rejection of either $P$ or $Q$ from $\mathbf n$, i.e., $P-(\mathbf n\cdot P)\mathbf n$ or $Q-(\mathbf n\cdot Q)\mathbf n$.

You can also use the Plücker matrix representation of a line in order to compute this point directly: if the homogeneous coordinate vectors of the two points are $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$, then the intersection of the line through these points and the plane $\mathbf\pi$ is $$(\mathbf p\mathbf q^T-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T)\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf\pi^T\mathbf q)\mathbf p - (\mathbf\pi^T\mathbf p)\mathbf q.$$ In your case, $\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf n;0)^T$, so the above formula translates into inhomogeneous Cartesian coordinates as $${(\mathbf n\cdot Q)P-(\mathbf n\cdot P)Q \over \mathbf n\cdot Q-\mathbf n\cdot P}.$$ Assuming that the line goes in the direction of $Q$ from $P$, this simplifies to $${(\mathbf n\cdot Q)P-(\mathbf n\cdot P)Q \over \lVert P-Q\rVert}.$$ You’ve already computed this denominator when you found the unit vector $\mathbf n$. This can be further expanded in terms of $Q-P$ instead of $\mathbf n$, but since you need $\mathbf n$ anyway, the orthogonal rejection described earlier is less expensive to compute.

Comment: For that matter, you could use Plücker matrices or Plücker coordinates directly for your representation after normalizing them in some way that also captures the line’s direction.